# How to set table name in Loopback 4 on a model that is wrapped in mixin?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

I need to explicitly set database table name on a Loopback 4 model. I do that using `@model` decorator as shown below:

```js
@model({settings: {postgresql: {schema: 'public', table: 'dbtablename'}}})
class MyModel extends Entity {
...
```

In simple case, it works fine. However I need to now *extend* the model using an `AuditMixin` that adds timestamp property to the model. This takes in the model declared above and returns an extented model.

Here is the code for the mixin:

```js
import {MixinTarget} from '@loopback/core';
import {property} from '@loopback/repository';

export function AuditMixin<T extends MixinTarget<object>>(baseClass: T) {
  class Mixin extends baseClass {
    timestamp: Date;
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(args);
      this.timestamp= new Date();
    }
  }
  return Mixin;
}
```

Mixin usage:

```js
class MyModelWithMixin extends AuditMixin(MyModel) {}
```

The issue:

Loopback doesn't seem to respect the table name I provide in the decorator. In my database logs I can see it tries to access table `public.mymodelwithmixin`. Database log line is:

```
ERROR: relation "public.mymodelwithmixin" does not exist at character xyz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple: I needed to decorate where I used the mixin.

```js
@model({
  settings: {postgresql: {schema: 'public', table: 'dbtablename'}},
})
class MyModelWithMixin extends AuditMixin(MyModel) {}
```